# Why do I get null email when I sign in with Apple in Android with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I keep getting a `null` email whenever I sign in with Apple. Note that the display name is not null. Also, I've made sure to revoke any tokens before trying to Sign in with Apple again because as per my understanding, Apple only provides the email once, in the initial sign-up. Here is my code for signing in with Apple in Android with Firebase:

The OAuth provider:

```
fun appleOAuthProvider(appLanguage: String): OAuthProvider {

    return OAuthProvider
        .newBuilder("apple.com")
        .setScopes(listOf("name", "email"))
        .addCustomParameter("locale", currentLanguageLocale(appLanguage))
        .build()

} //: FUN
```

Signing in:

```
private fun singInUser(
    auth: FirebaseAuth,
    context: Context,
    appLanguage: String,
    isSigningIn: MutableState<Boolean>,
    completion: (FirebaseUser?) -> Unit
) {

    auth
        .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(context.getActivity(), HelperFunctions.appleOAuthProvider(appLanguage))
        .addOnSuccessListener { authResult ->

            Log.d("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "activitySignIn:onSuccess:${authResult.user}")
            completion(authResult.user)

        } //: ON SUCCESS

        .addOnFailureListener { e ->

            Log.w("SIGN IN WITH APPLE", "activitySignIn:onFailure", e)
            isSigningIn.value = false
            completion(null)

        } //: ON FAILURE

} //: FUN
```

After signing in, I collect the user's data with the `authResult.user` I previously got:

```
private fun collectDataFromApple(
    user: FirebaseUser?,
    completion: (SignInResult) -> Unit
) {

    val uid = user?.uid
    val email = user?.email
    var firstName = separatedFullName(user?.displayName)?.get(0)
    var lastName = separatedFullName(user?.displayName)?.get(1)

    if (firstName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        firstName = lastName
    } else if (lastName.isNullOrEmpty()){
        lastName = firstName
    }

    completion(
        SignInResult(
            data =
            UserData(
                personalInformation = UserData.PersonalInformation(
                    userID = uid,
                    email = email,
                    firstName = firstName,
                    lastName = lastName,
                    imageBitmap = null,
                    isNewUser = true,
                    isEmailVerified = mutableStateOf(true),
                    firebaseHasData = false
                ),
                addressInformation = UserData.AddressInformation(),
                contributeStatistics = UserData.ContributeStatistics()
            ),
            errorMessage = null
        )
    )

} //: FUN
```

The `user?.email` returns null for an unknown reason. The `firstName` and `lastName` are not null, however. Why is that?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, the sign up is successful and the user is visible in the authentication tab in Firebase. Even their email is visible in the Firebase console, but when I try to get it by calling FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.email, it returns null.

Comment: Instead of describing what you're doing, please edit your question and add that code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I did. Please let me know if you can be of help!

Comment: I still don't see where in code, `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.email`, returns null. Besides that, are you sure the user is authenticated when you check that?

Comment: In the "collectDataFromApple" function above, I have a 'FirebaseUser' object as a parameter. From this parameter, I am trying to get the user's email like that: "val email = user?.email". However, this returns null. If I try to get the user's display name, it does not return null. I am certain the user is authenticated since they are register in firebase console and I can fetch their uid and display name.

Comment: Did you try to use something like this `user.getProviderData().get(1).getEmail()`? Does it work that way?

Comment: Blimey, that did the trick! Thank you! Do you know why I have to get the second item from the list and not the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you authenticate your users in Firebase using the Facebook provider, the email address of the user is not present inside the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object. So to solve this, you have to read the list of providers and get the second provider as in the following lines of code:

```
val auth = Firebase.auth
val email = auth.currentUser?.providerData?.get(1)?.email
```

> Do you know why I have to get the second item from the list and not the first one?

The [FirebaseUser#getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getProviderData()) method returns an object of type [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) which:

> Represents a collection of standard profile information for a user. Can be used to expose profile information returned by an identity provider, such as Google Sign-In or Facebook Login.

Typically, the first element (index 0) in the `providerData` list corresponds to the user's primary authentication provider which is Google, and the second element (index 1) corresponds to the secondary provider, which, in this case, is **Apple**, in your use-case.

If you want to have the email present inside the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object as well, then I recommend you update the object using [FirebaseUser#updateEmail(email)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#updateEmail(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Note that the issue I had was with Apple, not Facebook, but I suppose this applies here as well.